# Combine multiple excel sheets with same header with unique id

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having trouble combing MULTIPLE sheets (can be more than 2 sheets) in one.
Basically I have sheets with same column what I want is to combine them.

Example: This is just a scenario but can we have a dynamic code for more than 2 sheets, the Unique ID can be shuffle. But basically this is what I'm trying to achieve (output), combining the data on different sheets in one.

[image: Sample Scenario]

I tried to use the ADO and make query for UNION and INNER JOIN (because I think it will work) but no luck.
Hope anyone can help me.

Comment: Please show the code you tried with ADO.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Sub test()
    Dim vDB, Temp
    Dim Ws(1 To 3) As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, j As Integer

    Set Ws(1) = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set Ws(2) = Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set Ws(3) = Sheets("Output")

    vDB = Ws(1).Range("a1").CurrentRegion
    Temp = Ws(2).Range("a1").CurrentRegion

    For i = 2 To UBound(vDB, 1)
        For j = 2 To UBound(vDB, 2)
            If Temp(i, j) <> "" Then
                vDB(i, j) = Temp(i, j)
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    Ws(3).Range("a1").Resize(UBound(vDB, 1), UBound(vDB, 2)) = vDB
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Sub SheetCode()
    For Each sh In Sheets
        If sh.Name <> Name Then
            For Each cl In sh.Range("B2:D4")
                If cl.Value <> "" Then Range(cl.Address).Value = cl.Value
            Next
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

This code assumes the tables are exactly identical in all sheets i.e. Headers & Unique IDs are in the same sequence.

Paste the code in Sheet where you want the data to be collected.

Comment: That will do if the sheet is on the same workbook and same sequence of unique id what if not? Also, what if I have more than 2 sheets to compare and in different workbooks?

Comment: @PaulJayceeSalvador in that case you need to be much more specific in your initial question AND your short example should be more representative of your data.